# Split string with commas also splits ampersands

Tags: python, html-parser

The code below parses an HTML, the trouble is splitting when ampersands appear in the data.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

data = '<HTML><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"></head>'\
'<body>107,1,236,1000,70,498,NameA NameB & NameC - ActionA ActionB</body></html>'

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
      def handle_data(self, data):
            print data.split(',')

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(data)
```

**Output**
It is splitting the '&' instead of only commas.

```
['107', '1', '236', '1000', '70', '498', 'NameA NameB ']
['&']
[' NameC - ActionA ActionB']
```

Thanks

Comment: It's splitting on comma only. The HTML parser treats "&" as a separate token though.

Comment: A lone `&` isn't valid in a PCDATA section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think this is the way to go,

```
data2 = data.replace('&', 'and')
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution, fetch value in `<body>` tag and parse using `data.split(',')` using Beautifulsoup or any library of your choice.